# Modeling global warming with a sinusoidal fit in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to model global warming from temperature records recorded daily from June 1920 to October 2019 in Montélimar on Python. To do this, I would first like to model these seasonal variations by a sinusoidal fit.

Here is the sinusoidal model that I have reproduced: $$T(t) = A \sin(\omega t + \phi) + B$$ where the parameters A (amplitude),  (phase) and B (average temperature) are fitted to the data with $$\omega = \frac{2 \pi}{365}$$

However, such a model fitted to the whole data set does not give any increase in average temperature. I therefore try to apply a sinusoidal fit for each decade.

I first plotted the data in the data file like this:

```py
# Import of modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Read the montelimar_temperature containing the data
Date, Temperature = np.loadtxt('montelimar_temperature.dat', unpack = True)
Date = Date + 2400000.5 # Conversion of dates from Modified Julian Days to Julian Days
date_new = pd.to_datetime(Date, unit = 'D', origin = "julian") # Convert Julian Days dates to datetime64 format

# Size of the graph
plt.figure(figsize = (25, 9))

# Plot of the curve
plt.plot(date_new, Temperature)

# Title and others
plt.title("Evolution of daily recorded temperatures in Montélimar between 1920 and 2020", fontsize = 30) # Title
plt.xlabel("Year", fontsize = 20) # Title of the absissa
plt.ylabel("Temperature (°C)", fontsize = 20) # Title of the ordinates
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Then I created a time variable so I could do my decadal average. I applied the sine fit to all the decades in the data file, then plotted the entire graph with the fit. You will find my code below. It works flawlessly, but I feel like I'm repeating myself a lot with the code. I feel like I could do this without so much repetition, but every time I try I get errors and my graphs don't plot correctly. That's why I would like to know if there is a way to rewrite this in a cleaner way.

Here is the code I would like to simplify:

```py
# Definition of the function for sinusoidal adjustment
def sinLaw(t, A, phi, B):
    omega = (2 * np.pi) / 365
    return A * np.sin(omega * t + phi) + B

import datetime

current_decade = np.datetime64(date_new[0], 'Y')
time_for_B = np.linspace(1930, 2020, 10)
#print(time_for_B)
count_time = np.array([]) # Variable to store the temperatures of a decade
count_date = np.array([])
B_list = np.array([])
n = 1

for i in range(0, len(date_new)): # Browse the date_new indexes to simply access the date_new value and the corresponding temperature
    if np.datetime64(date_new[i], 'Y') >= current_decade + np.timedelta64(10, 'Y'): # Arrived at a new decade
        current_decade = current_decade + np.timedelta64(10, 'Y') # Change in the current decade
        n = n + 1
        plt.figure(n)
        plt.plot(count_date, count_time)
        
        N = len(count_date)
        time_model = np.linspace(0, N, N)
        # Fit of the linear model
        solution = curve_fit(sinLaw, time_model, count_time)
        # Identification of the parameters
        A, phi, B = solution[0]
        # Display the result
        #print('A = {:4.2f} amplitude'.format(A))
        #print('B = {:4.2f} °C'.format(B))
        #print('phi = {:4.2f} radians'.format(phi))
        # Display the sine fit
        y = sinLaw(time_model, A, phi, B)
        B_list = np.append(B_list, B)
        plt.plot(count_date, y)
        
        errors = 5. * np.ones(y.shape)
        
        # Fit of the linear model
        solution, pcov = curve_fit(sinLaw, time_model, y, sigma = errors, absolute_sigma = True)
        
        # Identification of the model parameters
        A, phi, B = solution
        
        # Calculation of the uncertainty on the fitted parameters
        perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
        
        # Display
        print('B = {:5.7f} ± {:5.3f} °C'.format(B, perr[0]))
        
        count_time = np.array([])
        count_date = np.array([])
        
    count_time = np.append(count_time, Temperature[i])
    count_date = np.append(count_date, date_new[i])

n = n + 1
plt.figure(n)
plt.plot(count_date, count_time, '.')

N = len(count_date)
time_model = np.linspace(0, N, N)
# Fit of the linear model
solution = curve_fit(sinLaw, time_model, count_time)
# Identification of the parameters
A, phi, B = solution[0]
# Display the result
#print('A = {:4.2f} amplitude'.format(A))
#print('B = {:4.2f} °C'.format(B))
#print('phi = {:4.2} radians'.format(phi))
# Display the sine fit
y = sinLaw(time_model, A, phi, B)
B_list = np.append(B_list, B)
plt.plot(count_date, y)
#print('B =', B_list)
plt.grid()
plt.figure(n + 1)
plt.plot(time_for_B, B_list)
plt.grid()

# Definition of the table of measurement errors
errors = 0.117 * np.ones(B_list.shape)

solution, pcov = curve_fit(sinLaw, time_model, count_time)

# Identification of the model parameters
A, phi, B = solution

perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))

# Display
print('B = {:5.7f} ± {:5.3f} °C'.format(B, perr[0]))

# Graphical representation of the data with the error bars
plt.errorbar(time_for_B, B_list, yerr = errors, marker = '+', linestyle = '')

# Graph option
plt.xlabel('Date [year]')
plt.ylabel('B [°C]')
plt.show()
```

Here is the result I get with this code and which corresponds to what I expect: [image: output]

I can't put all the data of my file here because it contains 36296 lines and I can't attach a file but you will find below a sample of the first 100 lines of my file which has the name "montelimar_temperature.dat":

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 22553 | 22.6 |
| 22554 | 22.6 |
| 22555 | 24.8 |
| 22556 | 17.5 |
| 22557 | 16.5 |
| 22558 | 18.3 |
| 22559 | 18.1 |
| 22560 | 16.8 |
| 22561 | 17.0 |
| 22562 | 17.5 |
| 22563 | 18.0 |
| 22564 | 17.8 |
| 22565 | 17.7 |
| 22566 | 17.6 |
| 22567 | 16.9 |
| 22568 | 18.0 |
| 22569 | 18.4 |
| 22570 | 17.4 |
| 22571 | 19.8 |
| 22572 | 21.0 |
| 22573 | 22.5 |
| 22574 | 20.6 |
| 22575 | 19.6 |
| 22576 | 21.7 |
| 22577 | 22.6 |
| 22578 | 21.7 |
| 22579 | 21.4 |
| 22580 | 21.6 |
| 22581 | 19.6 |
| 22582 | 20.2 |
| 22583 | 18.0 |
| 22584 | 22.4 |
| 22585 | 22.7 |
| 22586 | 19.4 |
| 22587 | 13.6 |
| 22588 | 16.8 |
| 22589 | 16.0 |
| 22590 | 15.2 |
| 22591 | 15.0 |
| 22592 | 14.1 |
| 22593 | 17.7 |
| 22594 | 15.7 |
| 22595 | 16.4 |
| 22596 | 14.4 |
| 22597 | 19.8 |
| 22598 | 17.2 |
| 22599 | 19.4 |
| 22600 | 15.3 |
| 22601 | 14.3 |
| 22602 | 18.6 |
| 22603 | 18.8 |
| 22604 | 20.0 |
| 22605 | 16.6 |
| 22606 | 17.6 |
| 22607 | 16.0 |
| 22608 | 16.3 |
| 22609 | 16.2 |
| 22610 | 17.3 |
| 22611 | 15.4 |
| 22612 | 14.4 |
| 22613 | 13.0 |
| 22614 | 18.4 |
| 22615 | 16.0 |
| 22616 | 13.4 |
| 22617 | 11.9 |
| 22618 | 12.8 |
| 22619 | 11.6 |
| 22620 | 12.2 |
| 22621 | 11.0 |
| 22622 | 13.6 |
| 22623 | 14.0 |
| 22624 | 11.2 |
| 22625 | 10.3 |
| 22626 | 10.2 |
| 22627 | 6.8 |
| 22628 | 10.2 |
| 22629 | 10.0 |
| 22630 | 8.2 |
| 22631 | 8.0 |
| 22632 | 8.8 |
| 22633 | 8.0 |
| 22634 | 9.8 |
| 22635 | 8.0 |
| 22636 | 5.6 |
| 22637 | 7.8 |
| 22638 | 7.2 |
| 22639 | 5.6 |
| 22640 | 5.9 |
| 22641 | 6.9 |
| 22642 | 6.0 |
| 22643 | 6.6 |
| 22644 | 8.7 |
| 22645 | 11.5 |
| 22646 | 11.0 |
| 22647 | 8.9 |
| 22648 | 9.4 |
| 22649 | 8.9 |
| 22650 | 5.1 |
| 22651 | 1.5 |
| 22652 | 5.3 |

The columns have no names. The first column corresponds to dates in Modified Julian Days and the second column corresponds to temperatures in degrees Celsius.

Comment: Making some guesses, downloading Montelimar mean temperature with no blending, the return format is NOT the format that you've shown, which means that you're likely pre-processing and have not described this. The returned format is a five-column CSV with full headers and a significant preamble. So... what are you actually doing?

Comment: p.s. the downloaded data from your indicated website do not use Julian time either. So this question is incomplete.

Comment: p.p.s. You're violating the terms of use of the dataset, which require a citation to the _Int. J. of Climatol._

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Reinderien. I just added a sample of the data file. I did provide my entire code. The original format of the data file is indeed a `.dat` format and not a `.csv`. If the link does not work anymore I will remove it. I apologize for this inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

The original format of the data file is neither a `.dat` nor a `.csv` (strictly), but a text file with a descriptive preamble followed by comma-separated data. This file, generated by

1. visiting https://www.ecad.eu/dailydata/customquery.php,
2. selecting non-blended, FRANCE, MONTELIMAR, "Mean temperature";
3. Next, download.
4. Unzip the file "ECA_non-blended_custom.zip"
5. Use "TG_SOUID106765.txt"

is first of all richer than the `.dat` that you have depicted as it contains this:

```
EUROPEAN CLIMATE ASSESSMENT & DATASET (ECA&D), file created on 14-03-2022
THESE DATA CAN BE USED FREELY PROVIDED THAT THE FOLLOWING SOURCE IS ACKNOWLEDGED:

Klein Tank, A.M.G. and Coauthors, 2002. Daily dataset of 20th-century surface
air temperature and precipitation series for the European Climate Assessment.
Int. J. of Climatol., 22, 1441-1453.
Data and metadata available at http://www.ecad.eu

FILE FORMAT (MISSING VALUE CODE IS -9999):

01-06 STAID: Station identifier
08-13 SOUID: Source identifier
15-22 DATE : Date YYYYMMDD
24-28 TG   : mean temperature in 0.1 &#176;C
30-34 Q_TG : Quality code for TG (0='valid'; 1='suspect'; 9='missing')

This is the series (SOUID: 106765) of FRANCE, MONTELIMAR (STAID: 786)
See file sources.txt for more info.
```

and second of all includes five columns instead of just two. Pandas can process this trivially, via

```py
def load(filename: str) -> tuple[
    pd.DataFrame,
    str,  # citation
]:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=filename,
        skiprows=21,
        skipinitialspace=True,
        parse_dates=['DATE'],
        infer_datetime_format=True,
    )
    valid_quality = 0
    df = df[df.Q_TG == valid_quality]

    with open(filename) as f:
        for _ in range(3):
            next(f)
        citation = ' '.join(line.rstrip() for line in itertools.islice(f, 3))

    return df, citation
```

This is far more preferable compared to the Julian-calendar processing that you have shown. As I mentioned in the comments, if you don't acknowledge that source in a citation you're violating the terms of use of the data set.

Add type hints.

Use `n += 1` in-place addition rather than `n = n + 1`.

Are you sure that this:

```
np.linspace(0, N, N)
```

does what you think? From 0 to N, spaced one apart, there would be N+1 and not N points. So it's likely that you actually just want `np.arange(N)`.

`5. * np.ones(y.shape)` should use `np.full_like` instead of multiplication. Same for `0.117 * np.ones(B_list.shape)`.

Use f-strings for your progress prints.

It is an anti-pattern to initialize a zero-sized Numpy array and iteratively grow it, as in `count_time` and `count_date`. These should be pre-allocated at the correct size.

Your code needs more functions. I've demonstrated how to add some but there need to be more.

### Suggested

Example code covering some of the above:

```py
import itertools

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def load(filename: str) -> tuple[
    pd.DataFrame,
    str,  # citation
]:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=filename,
        skiprows=21,
        skipinitialspace=True,
        parse_dates=['DATE'],
        infer_datetime_format=True,
    )
    valid_quality = 0
    df = df[df.Q_TG == valid_quality]

    with open(filename) as f:
        for _ in range(3):
            next(f)
        citation = ' '.join(line.rstrip() for line in itertools.islice(f, 3))

    return df, citation


def plot_simple(df: pd.DataFrame, citation: str) -> plt.Figure:
    fig: plt.Figure
    ax: plt.Axes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 9))
    ax.plot(df.DATE, df.TG)

    fig.suptitle("Evolution of daily recorded temperatures in Montélimar between 1920 and 2020")
    ax.set_title(citation)
    ax.set_xlabel("Year")
    ax.set_ylabel("Temperature (°C)")
    ax.grid()
    return fig


def plot_process(df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    date_new = df.DATE
    temperature = df.TG

    # Definition of the function for sinusoidal adjustment
    def sin_law(t: np.ndarray, A: float, phi: float, B: float) -> np.ndarray:
        omega = (2 * np.pi) / 365
        return A * np.sin(omega * t + phi) + B

    current_decade = np.datetime64(date_new.iloc[0], 'Y')
    time_for_B = np.linspace(1930, 2020, 10)

    count_time = np.array([])  # Variable to store the temperatures of a decade
    count_date = np.array([])
    B_list = np.array([])
    n = 1

    # Browse the date_new indexes to simply access the date_new value and the corresponding temperature
    for i in range(0, len(date_new)):
        if np.datetime64(date_new.iloc[i], 'Y') >= current_decade + np.timedelta64(10, 'Y'):  # Arrived at a new decade
            current_decade = current_decade + np.timedelta64(10, 'Y')  # Change in the current decade
            n += 1
            plt.figure(n)
            plt.plot(count_date, count_time)

            N = len(count_date)
            time_model = np.arange(N)

            solution = curve_fit(sin_law, time_model, count_time)

            # Identification of the parameters
            A, phi, B = solution[0]
            y = sin_law(time_model, A, phi, B)
            B_list = np.append(B_list, B)
            plt.plot(count_date, y)

            errors = np.full_like(y, 5)

            # Fit of the linear model
            solution, pcov = curve_fit(sin_law, time_model, y, sigma=errors, absolute_sigma=True)

            # Identification of the model parameters
            A, phi, B = solution

            # Calculation of the uncertainty on the fitted parameters
            perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))

            # Display
            print(f'B = {B:5.7f} ± {perr[0]:5.3f} °C')

            count_time = np.array([])
            count_date = np.array([])

        count_time = np.append(count_time, temperature.iloc[i])
        count_date = np.append(count_date, date_new.iloc[i])

    n += 1
    plt.figure(n)
    plt.plot(count_date, count_time, '.')

    N = len(count_date)
    time_model = np.arange(N)
    # Fit of the linear model
    solution = curve_fit(sin_law, time_model, count_time)
    # Identification of the parameters
    A, phi, B = solution[0]

    # Display the sine fit
    y = sin_law(time_model, A, phi, B)
    B_list = np.append(B_list, B)
    plt.plot(count_date, y)

    plt.grid()
    plt.figure(n + 1)
    plt.plot(time_for_B, B_list[:len(time_for_B)])
    plt.grid()

    # Definition of the table of measurement errors
    errors = np.full_like(B_list, 0.117)

    solution, pcov = curve_fit(sin_law, time_model, count_time)

    # Identification of the model parameters
    A, phi, B = solution

    perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))

    # Display
    print('B = {:5.7f} ± {:5.3f} °C'.format(B, perr[0]))

    # Graphical representation of the data with the error bars
    plt.errorbar(
        time_for_B,
        B_list[:len(time_for_B)],
        yerr=errors[:len(time_for_B)],
        marker='+', linestyle='',
    )

    # Graph option
    plt.xlabel('Date [year]')
    plt.ylabel('B [°C]')


def main() -> None:
    df, citation = load('TG_SOUID106765.txt')
    plot_simple(df, citation)
    plot_process(df)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice and suggestions. `np.linspace(0, N, N)` does what I want. It allows me to have N elements precisely.
Regarding the code example you provided, the `load` function gives the following error: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` because the first column is a date object.

Comment: Update your version of Python. Your diagnosis of the problem is not correct. Your version of Python does not support type hints.